# How to change context root path from http://host:port/app_name to only an app_name in Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, web.xml, contextpath

How can I change context root path from http://host:port/app_name to only an **app_name** in web.xml file or another way in Dynamic Web Project.

Actually, I'm facing an issue to import local javascript, css and other resources into my view say html/jsp.

for example, I have some js and css files inside resources folder of web-content.
Now to import these I'm using below code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/appname/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/appname/resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/appname/resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/appname/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

So now I want to change **http://localhost:8080/appname/** to the only **appname/** means `<script type="text/javascript" src="appname/resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>` as host and port dynamic in nature and can be changed anytime. So how can I achieve it.

Comment: How does this question relate to programming in the Java language?

Comment: Have you tried using the File Search to do a string replacement?